# Hide the keyboard whenever I want in the app on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I've read several answers to similar question but none of them are satisfying. I want to open and close the keyboard whenever I want.

This is what I've found:

> Set the following to your activity inside AndroidManifest.xml
>
> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
>
> Or in onCreate of your activity's code:
>
> getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

is this the correct way to do it?
I don't understand why there isn't a simple way to open and close it.

Comment: use the first one(android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

Show it via: `iMM.showSoftInput(ed, 0);`

Hide it via: `iMM.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);`